# Xamarin Forms (running on iOS): Unable to file a storyboard file when building

Tags: ios, xamarin, nib, file-not-found

I am having the following error, and even after I clean or rebuild, the error still appears. Isn't that file auto generated by Xamarin?

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Users/simonlam/Desktop/Application Repository/App/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.4-9.3/ibtool-link/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/01J-lp-oVM-view-Ze5-6b-2t3.nib does not exist
>   File name: '/Users/simonlam/Desktop/Application Repository/App/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.4-9.3/ibtool-link/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/01J-lp-oVM-view-Ze5-6b-2t3.nib'
>     at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x000d1] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002e] in <8cce4f82936e41b29850baed19c7dcc5>:0 
>     at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x00121] in <8cce4f82936e41b29850baed19c7dcc5>:0

Comment: the file may be created automatically by the project template, but you can still delete/rename/break it.  If you have removed it, check your info.plist to see if there is a reference to it.

Comment: Under the info.plist ->Deployment Info, the Main Interface section was left blank but not sure whether it was blank before coz I have not touched that part. Now I put LaunchScreen in there but the error still there.

Comment: Do you have a LaunchScreen.storyboard file in your iOS app project? Do you have a Launch Screen specified in the Info.plist->Launch Images->LaunchScreen field? If so, try removing it if you do not want to use a storyboard for your launch screen.

Comment: Thanks, I think I solved by removing the obj folder which it auto generated when compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by remove the auto generated folders. Since it regenerated when compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - I had to run the Xcode and install the latest updates, after that re-open the solution in VS